# Excel match with a list as criteria

Tags: excel, excel-match

I want to perform a match in excel using, several criteria (text, string) in the form of a list. For example:

```
Match(A:A & B:B, C:C & D:D, 0) (With the array parenthesis of course)
```

I have try this, but it doesn´t work.

I also looked in the internet, and found nothing similar

Any idea how could I do it?

Regards.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Consider rewording and including an image of your spreadsheet.

Comment: The question is clear.... you have a list in column A, another in B, another in C and another in D, and want to search if something from A&B (concatenated) matches to something from C:D (concatenated). Regards.

Comment: Ok, so you want to return the row number of the first row where A&B concatenated matches C&D concatenated?

Comment: Yes, that´s right.

Answer (score 0):

In order to return the first row number where `A&B` matches `C&D`, type the following array formula:

```
= MATCH(TRUE,(A:A&B:B)=(C:C&D:D),0)
```

Note: This is an array formula, meaning you must press Ctrl+Shift+Enter in the cell after typing the formula.

Also note: This formula takes a relatively long time to calculate because it checks the entire columns. I recommend narrowing the formula to a certain amount of rows as required.

For example,

```
= MATCH(TRUE,(A1:A10&B1:B10)=(C1:C10&D1:D10),0)
```

accomplishes the same thing but only checks the first 10 rows of the spreadsheet, thus drastically reducing the calc time.

Comment: Sadly, this didn´t work for me.  

I used the following formula;
    = MATCH(TRUE,(A2:A5&B2:B9)=(C1:C2000&D1:D2000),0).

Giving the error #N/A. (of course I've pressed Ctrl+Shift+Enter).

All data is in text format.

Comment: Well, the reason your formula isn't working is because all of the arrays inside the formula must be of the same size, i.e. `A2:A5&B2:B9` must be changed to `A1:A2000&B1:B2000` in order to match the size of your `C` and `D` arrays.

Comment: Well... that's sad... anyway...I will try to work around another way to solve my requirement... Thanks you very much Peter.

Comment: If you give more details in the spreadsheet, I don't mind helping you.